# What is this part? (DIP, 14 PIN, Fairchild Logo, 5036516 -00 8432)

Tags: identification, components

Found with a bunch of boxes with 74 Series Logic Chips.  Can't find a datasheet anywhere.

Text:

5036516

-00

8432

Indonesia

[image: Part]

Comment: This is Fairchild manufactured: PLA or PROM.

Comment: They look like house-numbered chips, marked to the spec of the customer, so unlikely to find a datasheet with that part number. That was not uncommon in the 1980s (that part was made in the 32nd week of 1984). There are some gadgets that claim to be able to identify random chips, not sure how well they work.

Comment: It's likely a custom chip for a specific customer. 8432 is the date code (32nd week of 1984).

Comment: If you have more than one, 1984 lithography isn’t that small so a normal microscope could see the structure inside clearly if you crack the capsule open.